# Bridging ReadOnlySpan<byte> and ReadOnlySpan<char>

Tags: c#

C#11 has added UTF-8 support in the shape of `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` but the `ISpanParseable` interface takes a `ReadOnlySpan<char>`. Is there a sensible (preferably zero allocation) way to convert between these two or is there a better way of parsing a UTF-8 `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` that's an integer string as an integer?

Comment: No, there is no ... for parsing you may use `System.Buffers.Text.Utf8Parser` static class ... maybe in future verios there will be [IUtf8SpanFormattable and IUtf8SpanParsable](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/81500)

Comment: char in c# is a class object where each object can be one or two bytes and there is a protected property indicating if the character is one or two bytes.  You need to use an encoding method to do the conversion because the properties in the char class are protected.

Comment: I think Utf8Parser solves my problem, thankyou!

Comment: @jdweng `char` is always 2 bytes, it's UTF16, so no these are not convertible. Source code is here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/7b91fd42a64732681472afc8d5a52c5bc5eb0c8a/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Char.cs#L45 and there is a recursive field of the same type (weird stuff to do with the way it's compiled) there is no private field that you speak of.

Comment: @Charlieface : No.  Characters like 0x00 to 0x7F are only one byte.

Comment: @jdweng that depends on what you mean; 0x00-0x7f will be *encoded* to one byte via UTF8 or ASCII, but they *fundamentally are* (in their `char` form, UTF-16): 2 bytes; you can't transparently pun between the two unless the recipient knows to compensate for unicode spacing

Comment: @MarcGravell : I strictly talking about the class char.  The object can contain two bytes but there is a private property that indicates if the object contain a character that is one or two bytes.  The private property is protected and only encoding methods have access to the property.

Comment: @jdweng except it is a `struct` (I'm happy to assume that you mean "class" in the IL sense), and as such is fixed size; it always fundamentally is: exactly 2 bytes (this is even defined in ECMA 334 §11.7.17); how that encodes / serializes is irrelevant and is not the same; that's like saying "but an `Int128` might have the value `7`, hence: 1 byte, not 16")

Comment: @jdweng That is categorically not true. They are *always* stored as two bytes, and the higher byte is often just `0x00`. You can see this in ECMA-334 as mentioned, but also ECMA-335 which is the spec for .NET: *"1.1.3 Character data type
A CLI char type occupies 2 bytes in memory and represents a Unicode code unit using UTF-16 encoding."*